# Vim tags with filenames containing a $

Tags: vim, ctags

When I have a ctags entry that is in a filename containing a `$` such as `foo/bar/File$With$Dollars.ext` vim won't open that file but will instead try to open `foo/bar/Baz.ext`. I tried making the output tag filename escape the `$` with `\$` - as you would do when opening that file with `:e foo/bar/File\$With\$Dollars.ext` - but that didn't work either.

Concretely, let's say I've got the following tag:

```
fooFunction     foo/bar/File$With$Dollars.ext   23;"    f
```

How can I make vim understand the `$` is part of the file name when that file name is supplied by a ctags tags file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not particularly good with vimscript, but I ended up doing this:

```
function SmaliFileFixTagFileName()
    let fname = expand("<afile>")
    let delbuf = 0
    if (stridx(fname, "$") != -1 )
        if (stridx(fname, "\\$") == -1)
            let fname = escape(fname, "$")
        else
            let delbuf = 1
        endif
    endif
    exe "silent doau BufReadPre " . fname | exe "edit " . fname | exe "silent doau BufReadPost " . fname
    if (delbuf == 1)
        exe "bd " . escape(escape(fname, "\\"), "$")
    endif
endfunction

augroup tagfix
    au!
    au BufReadCmd *.smali call SmaliFileFixTagFileName()
augroup end
```

and ensuring the tags were generated with filenames escaping the `$` as `\$`.

It works for what I need. I'll leave this open for a bit just in case anyone has a better solution.